# How to override cookie lifetime for a controller in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, session

I have searched this on google but did not find any thing helpful.

When a **user does login** using my **custom login page** then the **SID** should be **generated** such that its **lifetime is say 20 years** no matter what is set through the Admin.

Just to test, I have modified the following function in `/vendor/magento/framework/Session/Config.php` file 
to

```
protected function configureCookieLifetime()
    {
        $lifetime = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue($this->lifetimePath, $this->_scopeType);
        return $this->setCookieLifetime(0, 0); //Original syntax return $this->setCookieLifetime($lifetime, self::COOKIE_LIFETIME_DEFAULT);
    }
```

And after modifying when I login then It sets the **PHPSESSID** to year 2038. Which is what I want.

But how can I override this in my custom module so that I check if the controller is **"mycontroller"** then I set the lifetime to 0 otherwise normal core code will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can used below code to set cookie into your custom extension.

```
$OM = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cookieManager = $OM->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');
$cookieMetadataFactory = $OM->get("Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory");
$cookie_lifetime = (50 * 60); //50 days
$cookie_metadata = $cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata()->setDuration($cookie_lifetime); 
$cookieManager->setPublicCookie('cookie1', 'value', $cookie_metadata);
```